# Deleting the oldest record using SQLite

Tags: html, sqlite

I want  to delete the oldest record from a table using SQLite so should i use a condition (the lowest id ) or there is another remedy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from table1 as a where a.id = (select min(id) from table1)
```

or if you have date saved you can do

```
delete from table1 as a where a.[date]= (select min([date]) from table1)
```